# When NetworkStream.Read(byte[], int, int) needs to return -1, it abort()s the thread it is running on instead?

Tags: c#, networking, stream

```
        NetworkStream stream = socket.GetStream();

        if (stream.CanRead)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int i = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
                result += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, i);
            }
        }
```

Above code was designed to retrieve message from a `TcpClient` while running on a separate thread. `Read` Method works fine until it is supposed to return -1 to indicate there is nothing to read anymore; instead, it just terminates the thread it is running on without any apparent reason - tracing each step using the debugger shows that it just stops running right after that line.

Also I tried encapsulating it with a `try ... catch` without much success.

What could be causing this?

EDIT: I tried

```
        NetworkStream stream = socket.GetStream();

    if (stream.CanRead)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int i = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
            if (i == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            result += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, i);
        }
    }
```

thanks to @JonSkeet, but the problem is still there. The thread terminates at that `read` line.

EDIT2: I fixed the code like this and it worked.

```
    while (stream.DataAvailable)
    {
        int i = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
        result += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, i);
    }
```

I think the problem was simple, I just didn't think thoroughly enough. Thanks everyone for taking a look at this!

Comment: You say "Also I tried encapsulating it with a try ... catch without much success." - can we *see* how you did that please?

Comment: Re your edit; do ***NOT*** use `DataAvailable` for this; that does not mean quite what you think it does, and will typically cause data errors. The only valid use for `DataAvailable` is for deciding things like "should I do the next read as sync vs async". It is working *by accident* with your edit; it is not a reliable solution to your scenario.

Comment: You might want to use my networking library (http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/05/griffin-networking-a-somewhat-performant-networking-library-for-net/) so that you don't have to write the networking layer by yourself.

Comment: @MarcGravell I see what you mean. So I added extra two lines of `int i = stream.Read(...)` and `result += ...` before the `while` loop to make sure stream is synchronized to the next incoming packet. This method will be called when I am 100% sure someone is sending me a packet anyway.

Comment: @Kenny "packet" is not synonymous with "send"; what you have available to you could be any of: an entire single message; several entire messages; half a message; one byte; the end of one message, an entire second message, and the start of a third message; various other crazy. Seriously, using DataAvailable, or thinking in terms of packets **is a mistake**. You must think in terms of a *stream*, and apply a "framing" methodology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like it is simply *blocking* - i.e. waiting on the end of the stream. For it to return a non-positive number, it is necessary **that the stream be closed**, i.e. the the caller has not only sent data, but has closed their outbound socket. Otherwise, the system cannot distinguish between "waiting for a packet to arrive" and "the end of the stream".

If the caller is sending one message only, they should close their outbound socket after sending (they can keep their inbound socket open for a reply).

If the caller is sending multiple messages, then you must use a framing approach to read individual sub-messages. In the case of a text-based protocol this usually means "hunt the newline".

Answer (score 5):

No, [`Stream.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx) returns 0 when there's nothing to read, not -1:

> **Return value**
>   The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This can be less than the number of bytes requested if that many bytes are not currently available, or zero (0) if the end of the stream has been reached.

My guess is that actually, no exception is being thrown and the thread isn't being aborted - but it's just looping forever. You should be able to see this if you step through in the debugger. Whatever's happening, your "happy" termination condition will never be hit...

Answer (score 3):

Since you're trying to read ASCII characters, from a stream, take a look at the following as a potentially simpler way to do it:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(Stream stream)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            yield return reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

While this may not be exactly what you want, the salient points are:

- Use a `StreamReader` to do all the hard work for you
- Use a while loop with `!reader.EndOfStream` to loop through the stream
- You can still use `reader.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)` if you'd prefer to read chunks into a buffer, and append to result. Just note that these will be `char[]` chunks not `byte[]` chunks, which is likely what you want.